# The space $\omega^\omega$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have encountered the following definitions in a [course I am reading](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/%7Etsaban/ICT/6.pdf), and I think that I don't fully understand some of the definitions:

**Definition 1:** For all $n<\omega$, and $\sigma:n \rightarrow \omega$, let $q_\sigma \in (\omega + 1)^\omega$ be such that: $q_\sigma |_n = \sigma$ and $q_\sigma(m) = \omega$ for all $m \geq n$.

**Definition 2:** Denote Iseq($\omega$):=$\{ \sigma:n \rightarrow \omega | n<\omega,\sigma   \text { is strictly increasing }\}$.

**Definition 3:** $(\omega+1)^{\uparrow \omega} = \{ f \in (\omega + 1)^\omega | n<m \rightarrow (f(n) < \omega) \rightarrow f(n) < f(m)) \text{ and } ((f(n) = \omega) \rightarrow f(m) = \omega) \}$

**Definition 4:** $Q = \{ q_\sigma = | \sigma \in Iseq(\omega) \}$

**Lemma 5:** Suppose that $\psi : (\omega+1)^{\uparrow \omega} \rightarrow \omega^\omega$ is continuous at $Q$. Then there exists an element $g \in \omega^\omega$ such that, for all $x \in \omega^{\uparrow \omega}$ and $n<\omega$:
$$x(n) > g(n) \Rightarrow \psi(x(n)) \leq g(n)$$

My questions:

1. I guess that in the two definitions, $n$ means $\{ 0,1,2,...,n-1 \}$?
2. Suppose for instance that , $\sigma = (1,2,3,4,5)$. Then, is $q_\sigma = (1,2,3,4,5,\omega,\omega,...)$? Or, does $q_\sigma = (1,2,3,4,5,\omega+1,\omega+1,...)$?
3. Is $\omega + 1 = [0,\omega]$, or is $\omega + 1 = [0,\omega+1]$?
4. Does Lemma 5 means that $\psi$ is "order reversing" for $x$? (which means somehow "turns" $x$ from "maximal" to "minimal" on $Q$). If not, is there a simple way to describe what the Lemma means?

   (In questions 2,3, my guess was that $\omega + 1 = [0,\omega] = [0,\omega+1)$ and that $q_\sigma = (1,2,3,4,5,\omega,\omega,\omega,\omega,...)$, but I saw something in one of the proofs that might suggest differently.)

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you could also provide a link to the text you are studying. Is it [this text](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~tsaban/ICT/6.pdf)?

Comment: Did you want to write $n<m$ instead of $f<m$ in Definition 3?

Comment: Yes! it is exactly this text.. and yes, I meant $n < m$ corrected.

Comment: It is more-or-less standard in texts using [von Neumann construction of ordinals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals) (which also encompasses [natural numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Constructions_based_on_set_theory)) that: a) Every ordinal is the set of all smaller ordinals. In particular, $\omega$ is the set of all natural numbers and $\omega+1=\omega\cup\{\omega\}$ contains all natural numbers and also the ordinal $\omega$. (So you are correct in saying that $\omega+1=[0,\omega]=[0,\omega+1)$.)

Comment: b) In particular, for any natural number $n\in\omega$ we have $n=\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$.

Comment: In your example in the second question you get $q_\sigma=(1,2,3,4,5,\omega,\omega,\omega,\dots)$. Note that this is a map from $\omega$ (domain consists of all natural numbers) to $\omega+1$ (all natural numbers and the ordinal $\omega$ are in the codomain). So it is an element of $(\omega+1)^\omega$.